# How to convert a link inside a string to a regular link?

Tags: javascript, hyperlink

I have a string like below

```
var result = "Here is the memory consumption : @10.11.10.22 : <a href='https://abc.mystats.com/static/mem3412671190.11.svg'>view</a>"
```

I need to show a link along side the regular text.Something like this

Here is the memory consumption : @10.11.10.22 : [view](http://abc.mystats.com/static/mem3412671190.11.svg)

I have looked into some of the javascript's methods like `link()` but I am not sure how to use it in my case. I can seperate out `https://abc.mystats.com/static/mem3412671190.11.svg` and hook it up to a `word` something like this

```
var word = "view";
var res = word.link("https://abc.mystats.com/static/mem3412671190.11.svg");
```

But then I need to show the word [view](https://abc.mystats.com/static/mem3412671190.11.svg) along side the regular text as shown above.How do I do it?

**Note**: I need to show this in a webpage where the user can see this text with the link.Currently this piece of string is what I get from the backend.

Comment: Where do you want to display this? In your HTML view?

Comment: @palaѕн yes in my HTML view.

Comment: I think this should work fine if you just do `document.body.innerHTML = result;` also like http://jsfiddle.net/bxt3h95y/

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [innerHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML) property to set the HTML within the designated element:

```js
const result_container = document.getElementById('result-container');
const result = 'Here is the memory consumption : @10.11.10.22 : <a href="https://abc.mystats.com/static/mem3412671190.11.svg">view</a>';

result_container.innerHTML = result;
```

```html
<div id="result-container"></div>
```